# How to put an object inside a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, oop, nested

I'm building a blackjack game in Python. How I've set it up is that each player object has a hand object which is just a list `self.hand = []` that can be filled up with card objects `self.hand = [<__main__.Card object at 0x7fb2c66b27f0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x7fb2c66b2730>]`. I want to introduce splitting into this game, so if two cards have the same value, then they get split up into 2 separate hands. I want to have the have my final hand attribute to look like this `self.hand = [[<__main__.Card object at 0x7fb2c66b27f0>], [<__main__.Card object at 0x7fb2c66b2730>]]` but I can't just use `list()` to wrap the card objects to a list. Can anyone advise on how to do this?

Comment: `self.hand.append([card_object])`

Comment: I'm not following what exactly you are asking. Apparently you already know how to put objects into a list – as you did for `self.hand`. What's stopping you from doing the same when that object is a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can either slice or destructure a list to divide it into multiple lists.

Here's an example using destructuring (given a list of two identical elements, divide the two elements into two lists of one element each):

```
>>> hand = [10, 10]
>>> if len(hand) == 2 and len(set(hand)) == 1:
...     [hand1, hand2] = hand
...     hand = [[hand1], [hand2]]
...
>>> hand
[[10], [10]]
```

Here's one using slicing (given a list of identical elements, split it in half):

```
>>> hand = [10, 10]
>>> if len(set(hand)) == 1:
...     hand = [hand[:len(hand)//2], hand[len(hand)//2:]]
...
>>> hand
[[10], [10]]
```

Another option could be to use a list comprehension to just wrap each element in another list:

```
>>> hand = [10, 10]
>>> if len(set(hand)) == 1:
...     hand = [[card] for card in hand]
...
>>> hand
[[10], [10]]
```

How exactly you apply this to your `Card` objects depends on how those objects are defined and constructed, which you didn't include in your question.  Note that using `len(set(hand))` to determine if the cards are identical will only work if `Card` implements `__hash__` to make itself hashable.